# connection between two distinct prime numbers $p,q$ such that $p^n=q^2+q+1$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p,q$ be two distinct prime number such that $p^n=q^2+q+1$, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$. I want to proof that, this forces $n=1$.

Comment: The RHS polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over the integers. Now conclude.

Comment: can you explain me any more? I dont know anything about RHS polynomial, please

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:conclude how? $x^2+x+1=\Phi_3(x)$, hence every prime factor of $x^2+x+1$ is $3$ or a prime $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, but we do not know much about the multiplicity of such prime factors.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over the integers, so there isn't a "common" factorisation to all the different numbers $q^2 + q + 1$, the way $q^2 - 1$ can always be factored as $(q-1)(q+1)$. That doesn't stop $q^2 + q + 1$ from having different non-trivial factorisations for different $q$. Most of all, that in itself doesn't stop $q^2 + q + 1$ from being a power of a prime for some $q$.

Comment: ...well I should be scurrying off from here. I'm actually taking a module in number theory this semester, but I have the more important topic of NMR spectroscopy.

Comment: please hint me!! I dont understand your answers !

Comment: Fact: $3^n=q^2+q+1$ has no solutions, hence if $p^n=q^2+q+1$ with $n\geq 2$, $q$ has to be a prime $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Now it is probably useful to work in the ring of Eistenstein integers, that is a UFD.

Comment: this fact $3^n=q^2+q+1$ has no solutions, is in a book? can you address me please?

Comment: @Rima: that is simple to prove, since it is equivalent to $$ 4\cdot 3^n-3 = (2q+1)^2$$

Comment: Why do you want to proof this?

Comment: because it is a part of my algebraic problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I borrowed two books on contest problems; this one is *An Introduction to Diophantine Equations*, [by Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, and Ion Cucurezeanu.](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817645489) Most of what is needed for your problem, probably all, is in section 4.2, The Ring of Integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d].$ This is mentioned above by Jack, suggesting working in the Eisenstein integers $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-3}],$ which is a UFD.
This is a pretty good start...

We have $x^2 + x + 1 = p^n;$ I am not sure yet whether the restriction that $x$ be prime matters. We have, page 168, the unit
$$  \omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt {-3}}{2}, $$
which is a cube root of $1.$ The main detail is that $\sqrt {-3}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-3}].$ On page 173 we have some examples of finding gcd of two quantities. Also on page 177, problem 2 is similar to yours, solution takes pages 315-319.  Note that
$$   \omega^2 = -1 - \omega,$$
$$     \omega -  \omega^2 =  \sqrt {-3}. $$
Alright, we have factorization
$$  (x - \omega)(x - \omega^2) = p^n.  $$
We need to know
$$ \gcd(x - \omega, x - \omega^2). $$ If some $\delta$ in the ring divides both, then it divides $     \omega -  \omega^2 =  \sqrt {-3}. $ However, this is irreducible, so
$$ \gcd(x - \omega, x - \omega^2)= 1. $$
It follows that each factor is such a power, that is
$$  x - \omega = (a + b \omega)^n, $$
for ordinary $a,b \in \mathbb Z.$ NOTE: remind me to put in alternatives
$$   x - \omega =  \omega(a + b \omega)^n, \; \; \;    x - \omega =  \omega^2(a + b \omega)^n.  $$
What I have so far is the implication
$ b = \pm 1;  $ let me do exponent $n=5.$

$$  x - \omega = (a + b \omega)^5, $$
$$  x - \omega = a^5 + 5 a^4 b \omega + 10 a^3 b^2 \omega^2 + 10 a^2 b^3 + 5 a b^4 \omega + b^5 \omega^2. $$
Remember $\omega^2 = -1 - \omega,$ so that
$$  x - \omega = (a^5 - 10 a^3 b^2 + 10 a^2 b^3 - b^5)  + (5 a^4 b  - 10 a^3 b^2   + 5 a b^4  - b^5 ) \omega. $$ The coefficient of $\omega$ needs to be $-1,$ that is
$$ (5 a^4 b  - 10 a^3 b^2   + 5 a b^4  - b^5 ) = -1 $$
and
$$ b(5 a^4   - 10 a^3 b   + 5 a b^3  - b^4 ) = -1. $$
Well, $b$ is an ordinary integer, and $b$ divides $-1.$ that is,
$$  b = \pm 1. $$
 Next, we need either
$$ 5 a^4   - 10 a^3    + 5 a   - 1  = -1, $$ or
$$ 5 a^4   + 10 a^3   - 5 a   - 1 = -1. $$ Either way,
divide out by $5a,$
$$ a^3 + 2 a^2 - 1 = 0  $$ OR
$$ a^3 - 2 a^2 + 1 = 0.  $$
The rational root theorem tells us that $a = \pm 1$ as well.

Answer (score 5):

Erdös and Selfridge proved that a product of consecutive integers can never be a perfect power. That is, the equation 
$$
x(x + 1)\cdots  (x + (m - 1)) = y^n 
$$
has no solutions in positive integers $x,y,m,n$ with $m,n > 1$. Also for
$$
x(x + 1)\cdots  (x + (m - 1))+1 = y^n 
$$
all solutions are explicitly known, see [here](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/biludone.pdf), and the reference to the paper of N. Abe. For $m=2$ we obtain the above equation $x^2+x+1=y^n$. There is no integer solution for $n>1$.

A related problem can be found in [Ribenboim's book](https://books.google.at/books/about/Catalan_s_conjecture.html?id=SOzuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), where he gives all solutions of the Diophantine equation
$$
y^2=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^k.
$$

Comment: i said if $n \geq 2$, then $p < q$. So $p-1 | (p^n -1)=q(q+1)$. but i dont continue it!

Comment: Look up the solution by Abe. Perhaps it is not so difficult.

Comment: By what? Abe? i dont understand your means

Comment: Click on my link and go to references: [1] N. Abe, On the Diophantine Equation $x(x + 1) \cdots (x + n) + 1 = y^2$, Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. 76 (2000), 16-17.

Comment: Ok, Thank a lot Dear Dietrich Burde